# Glider Flying Handbook page 5-6 error on effects of weight to stall speed?

Tags: aerodynamics, glider

I've been reading the FAA's Glider Flying Handbook, 2013 (FAA-H-8083-13A). Page 5-6 in [chapter 5](https://www.faa.gov/sites/faa.gov/files/regulations_policies/handbooks_manuals/aviation/glider_handbook/gfh_ch05.pdf) states the following, but it doesn't seem right to me.

> The heavy glider has a higher stall speed and a higher minimum
> controllable airspeed than an otherwise identical, but lighter,
> glider. The stall speed of a glider increases with the square root of
> the increase in weight. If the weight of the glider is doubled
> (multiplied by 2.0), then the stall speed increases by more than 40
> percent (1.41 is the approximate square root of 2; 1.41 times the old
> stall speed results in the new stall speed at the heavier weight). For
> example, a 540-pound glider has a stalling speed of 40 knots. The
> pilot adds 300 pounds of water ballast making the new weight 840
> pounds. The new stalling speed is approximately 57 knots (square root
> of √ 300 + 40 = 57).

Increase of stall speed is not proportional to the square root of the *raw increase in weight*, it's proportional to the square root of the percentage change in weight. So in this case, the new stall speed would be

```
= StallSpeed * sqrt(NewWeight / OriginalWeight)
= 40 * sqrt(840/540)
= ~49.9
```

Another way to see this is incorrect is to do what the example says at first and double the weight (`540 * 2 = 1080`), which should increase the stall speed by 40% to 56.4 knots. So surely only increasing the weight by 300 pounds doesn't have the same effect. And by the math at the end of the paragraph, `sqrt(540) + 40 = 63.2 knots` which is clearly not equal to 56.4 knots.

Am I correct in my thinking here, and there is an error in the handbook?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are correct.

The handbook is correct in the earlier example -- double the weight, stall speed increases by $\sqrt{2}$.

You are correct in the final example.